# How to update value of registered script variable on post back?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a field agt_count that stores a number of agents. The default value is set as 1 and is increased by one for each new agent that is loaded.

Apparently I cannot re-register a script variable once it has been set so I need to know a way that I can update the script variables value if the page load is registered as a postback.

```
protected void Page_Load()
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterScriptVariable("agtCount", app.GetFieldValue("agt_count"));
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterScriptVariable("agtCount", app.GetFieldValue("agt_count"));
        {
    }
```

Comment: Strange, I can't find a reference to RegisterScriptVariable in any documentation.  What version of .NET are you using?  Anyway, it would probably be simplest to use a label.  If you don't want the user to see it then make the label hidden.

Comment: Using .NET 2.0 currently... anyways, you're saying create a hidden field to store the value on page so that I can access it through js or something? I'm trying to find a way to update the script variable when the users stays on the same page. The agtCount script variable is updated once you navigate to a new page but not on the same page... weird

Comment: Right.  You can then use document.getElementById("IdOfControl") to get the input control created by ASP.NET.

Comment: This is what I am currently doing, although the value that is output into my debugger isn't actually updated until the page changes.